# System.NullReferenceException in View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a ASP.NET MVC application in VB.NET.
Up to now, I basically have all core functionalities up and runnin^g.
(It's a front end for a Entitiy-Value-Attribute DB with optional FileUpload for Value Entries.)

I used the repository Pattern to access the database.
My Controller/Details Function looks like that:

```
Function Details(Optional ByVal id As Integer = Nothing) As ActionResult
    ViewData("Message") = "All details."

    Dim value As value

    value = ValueRepo.GetByID(id)
    'i tried to validate and/or redirect here'

    Return View(value)
End Function
```

The Details View contains this piece of code below.

```
<div>
@* I tried to validate here too.. *@
    @If Model.fileID = 0 Then
        @Html.ActionLink("Download File[" + Model.filestorage.fileName + "][" + Model.filestorage.mimeType + "]", "GetFile", "FileStorage", New With {.id = Model.fileID}, Nothing)
    End If
</div>
```

If some user types in an ID that doesn't exist.
E.g. /value/details/IDthatdoesntexist

A `System.NullReferenceException` is being thrown on the @If Model.fileID line.
(Obviously because the Model is empty...)

I tried to validate various methods at the points marked in the code.
For example with IsDBNull, is Nothing et cetera, but the Model.fileID code always gets executed.
I also tried to try/catch the exception.

Thanks for reading / answering in advance, I am really stuck here for some time.

Comment: an `if Model isnot nothing` should work fine. Show us the code you used for that and we can better tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a null check for model before submitting the model:

```
Dim value As value    
value = ValueRepo.GetByID(id)
if value == null
//have some dummy values or something else
    End If
Return View(value)
```

Also in your view :

```
   @{
     If Model!=null
       If Model.fileID = 0 Then
            Html.ActionLink("Download File[" + Model.filestorage.fileName + "][" + Model.filestorage.mimeType + "]", "GetFile", "FileStorage", New With {.id = Model.fileID}, Nothing)
        End If
     End If
}
```

Comment: Indeed, I always forgot the dummy part (to instantiate a new empty one, I always tried to redirect to an Error Page). How dumb.
`If value Is Nothing Then value = New value() End If`
How can I display some Error now? Also pack it into the View?  
`ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "Coulndt retrieve entry.")` doesn't show anything.
Is this because these Model Errors only work when validation occurs?

Comment: can you update your code for that? ideally it should work may be you have written something wrong..And Yes Model Errors only work when validation occurs.

Comment: Why create a set of dummy values rather than just using a null/nothing model? You can as easily check `if model is nothing` as you can `if model.value="dummy value"`. Unless you are actually putting error information into the model (which there is no sign of in the question or answer) a dummy model sounds like its just an invitation to accidentally treat dummy values as real somewhere because you forgot to check. At least with a null/nothing it is very obvious if you are trying to use something you shouldn't.